# Angular: Import jQuery to global namespace inside lazy module

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-datatables

How can I import jQuery and other third party libraries from node_modules folder only for "lazy" module?

At the moment I am using "scripts" inside "angular.json" but this loads up jQuery in entire site.

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"
            ]
```

I am using Angular 9, Angular Datatable.

Comment: You can dynamically append the script to the document when your module loads

Comment: I've tried that. Inside script tag with "lazy" attribute, it created 3 chunks. I can go this way but I dont want 3 additional http calls to fetch these libraries. Can I bundle these libs in one file, create lazy bundle and import?

Comment: I don't see why you could not ?

Comment: how can I create bundle of these 3 libs? I want these files from node_modules.